# i want to change background after clicking Button in android with kotlin

Tags: android, button, background, kotlin

I want to change background after clicking Button

```
   var bm : Button = messeg
    bm . setOnClickListener {
        bm . background = R.color.green
    }
```

Error Log:

> Error:(35, 31) Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Drawable! was
>   expected Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
>
> > Compilation error. See log for more details

Comment: use bm.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green), in that case you should pass drawable

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`background` requires a `Drawable`, but you are passing a color resource.

1. You can use `setBackgroundColor` to set a color resource:

`bm.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green)`

2. `setBackgroundResource` can be used to set a drawable resource:

`bm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_resource)`

3. `background` property can be used to set a drawable:

`bm.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.green_resource)`

Answer (score 14):

The current accepted answer is wrong for setBackgroundColor(). In the given example, you set the color to the resource id, but you must pass the color directly.

This won't fail because both values are int, but you'll get weird colors.

Instead of that, you should retrieve first the color from the resource, then set it as background. Example :

```
val colorValue = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.green)
bm.setBackgroundColor(colorValue)
```

Comment: If 'context' does not work for you, try 'this' instead

Answer (score 0):

button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shapebutton)

Comment: Hi. You can improve your answer by adding some supporting information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).